# LoadRunner - Calling One Script from another

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, sap-fiori, sap-gui

I am currently working on the load testing of SAP application where in I need to trigger an action in the SAP Frontend - Fiori Screen and the corresponding response time is available in the SAP Backend (i mean SAP GUI screen).

I need to capture like this because there is no request for the particular action is captured in either Fiddler or via Browser Dev-Tools.

My Question is - Currently I have 2 scripts - **a. SAP Web b. SAP GUI**.

Can i call the SAP GUI script from the SAP Web script to capture the response time and write it in the log file. ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Can i call the SAP GUI script from the SAP Web script to capture the
> response time and write it in the log file.

Not that I am aware of.  If these two virtual users were the same architectural tier and language type, such as Winsock and HTTP, then you might consider a multi-protocol virtual user.   But here you have multiple breaks in architecture making the jump from an HTTP user to SAP GUI.  In general, you call down the stack and receive values back up the stack.  An HTTP virtual user calling SAP GUI would be calling from the bottom of the Application layer to the top of it.   This just doesn't work.

I think you have some tool issues to work out as well.  It is off that you would "Write it in a log file" when a full transaction model exists to send a timing record to the testing tool for analysis with other timing records/transactions.   You're not even taking advantage of in-tool capabilities using variants of lr_message(). This is before considering the lock contention of multiple users all attempting to write to the same file.  Look up lr_output_message() & lr_set_transaction() - one of these is likely a far better fit than the path you are on.